# Group actions and quotient groups

Tags: group-theory

> Let $H$ be a proper subgroup of $G$. By considering the natural action of $G$ on $G/H$, deduce that
>   $$
>   \bigcup_{g \in G} gHg^{-1} \neq G
> $$
>
> $G$ is a finite group acting on finite set $X$

I am trying to prove this. I have defined the map as:

$$ 
  G \times H \to H \\
  (g, h) \mapsto g.h = ghg^{-1}
$$

I'm not really sure how to go about deducing this, can anybody help?

Comment: Does $G$ have to be finite?

Comment: It seems they suggest to consider the natural action $(\cdot,\cdot)\colon G\times G/H\rightarrow G/H$?

Comment: @Bihc I've edited the question to include this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [Lagrange’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_(group_theory)) (or more elementary), you have a disjoint union
$$G = \bigsqcup_{T ∈ G/H} T.$$

Now, using this, rewrite the union of the problem by splitting up “$g ∈ G$” in the index as
$$\bigcup_{g ∈ G} gHg^{-1} = \bigcup_{T ∈ G/H} \Big(\bigcup_{τ ∈ T} τHτ^{-1}\Big),$$
Let $T ∈ G/H$ be a left coset of $H$ and $α, β ∈ T$. Then $T = αH$ and $β = αh$ for some $h ∈ H$. So $βHβ^{-1} = αhHh^{-1}α^{-1} = αHα^{-1}$. Therefore all conjugates of $H$ by elements of one given left coset are actually the same.

Therefore, if $σ \colon G/H → G,~T ↦ σ_T$ is a right inverse to the projection $G → G/H$ (which is the same as a system of representatives $σ_T;~T ∈ G/H$ for $G/H$), then

$$\bigcup_{g ∈ G} gHg^{-1} = \bigcup_{T ∈ G/H} σ_T H σ_T^{-1}.$$

The right side is *not* a disjoint union (why?). If $G$ is finite, compare with the partiton of $G$ into a disjoint union of left cosets of $H$ above. How many “summands” do both unions have? How large is each “summand”?